# "ABORT CALLED" in hacker rank

Tags: c++, arrays

The following mentioned code is what I tried to submit in hacker rank but don't know why it's showing me ABORT CALLED error in multiple cases. This code runs fine in my IDE. Is it something related to dynamic memory allocation? The code does pass some of the test cases. Can someone please guide me with what's happening here

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n {0};
    cin >> n;
    int *ptr = new int(n);
    for(int i =0; i <n ; i++) cin >> ptr[i];
   

    int begin =0, end = n-1;
    
    while(begin < end){
        swap(ptr[begin], ptr[end]);
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
    
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++) cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your bug is here: `int *ptr = new int(n);` allocates a single int and sets the value of that 1 element to n

Comment: Avoid dynamic memory allocation and use `std::vector`.  There is a constructor that allows you to set the size; or you can use `push_back()` in the input loop.

Comment: thanks, a lot i noticed where I went wrong